# Find the value of $\alpha$ such that given series Converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(n^{1/n} - 1\right)^{\alpha}$. I need to find the value of $\alpha$  for which the given series Converges.

Now , If I consider $\displaystyle n^{1/n} = e^{\dfrac{\ln n}{n}}$ then Using Taylor Series expansion

$n^{1/n} = 1 + \dfrac{\ln n }{n} + \dfrac{ (\ln n)^2}{2 n^2} + \ldots$

Then, we get the sum as  $\displaystyle \displaystyle \left(\dfrac{\ln n }{n} + \dfrac{ (\ln n)^2}{2 n^2} + \ldots\right)^{\alpha}$

After this step I am stuck . CAN anyone tell me how should I proceed forward ?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but $\alpha > 1$ since $\alpha=1$ diverges by the integral test. I don't know when it starts to work, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n^{1/n} - 1)^{\alpha}}{\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^{\alpha}} = 1. $$

So by the limit comparison test, the series in question converges if and only if

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)^{\alpha} $$

converges. Then by a suitable comparison (or by the integral test), this converges if and only if $\alpha > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer. Write $r_n := n^{1/n}-1$, so $n=(1+r_n)^n$. By the binomial expansion
$$
n = 1 + 
\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 1\end{pmatrix} r_n
+
\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 2\end{pmatrix} r_n^2
+
\dots
+
\begin{pmatrix}n \\ n\end{pmatrix} r_n^n.
$$
This allows one to get various estimates on $r_n$. For example, noting that all the elements above are nonnegative, we see that
$$
r_n^2 
\leq
\frac{n}{\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 2\end{pmatrix}}
=
\frac{2}{n-1}.
$$
Therefore, by the comparison test for nonnegative series, your series converges for every value of $\alpha$ for which the following "larger" series also converges
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{2}{n-1} \right)^{\alpha/2},
$$
i.e. for every $\alpha > 2$. This argument still doesn't tell you anything about $\alpha\leq 2$.